# Select device to make Screen capture video using DirectShow.net Library

Tags: .net, video-streaming, directshow, video-capture

Now, I can get video device(Webcam) and audio device(Microphone) and stream to make video capture. How to change device source from Webcam to screen to make screen capture video

I use getdeviceofcat to set the source filter

```
DsDevice.GetDevicesOfCat(FilterCategory.AudioInputDevice);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a filter which captures screen and sends the video down the stream. In DirectShow SDK there is a sample filter called PushSource and inside there is PushSourceDesktop. Compile it and insert to your graph as a source filter.

Comment: I find PushSourceDestop and compile that I will get PushSourceDestop.obj. How to insert it into my project and into graph? I'm newbie with this. Thank you

Comment: You should build this example and get PushSource.ax. Register it by running command "regsvr32 PushSource.ax" (or if you're using  http://www.infognition.com/GraphEditPlus just press Add in filters window and select this file). Then it will appear in DirectShow Filters category as "PushSource Desktop Filter".